# I have building that is on a 20 amp breaker along with outside lighting

Tags: electrical, lighting, circuit-breaker, outdoor

I bought my house almost two years ago and there is a building off to the side that is on the same circuit as an older security light on the side of my house and the breaker is a 20 amp, the breaker tripped a few time now i can not turn it on now. can i put a 30 amp breaker in place of the 20 amp?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I replace a 15 ampere circuit breaker with a 20 ampere breaker?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/36633/can-i-replace-a-15-ampere-circuit-breaker-with-a-20-ampere-breaker)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No!**

The wire is (almost certainly) only rated for 20A.  If the breaker is tripping because more than 20A is flowing, then uprating the breaker will mean more than 20A flows through the wires, your wires heat up, and your house burns down.

(If the breaker is tripping because it's a GFCI breaker and there is a ground fault, then a 30A GFCI breaker will also trip, and a 30A non-GFCI breaker will ignoring a serious fault.  A fault which can kill you.)

tl;dr: You need to find the fault which is causing the breaker to trip and fix it.